# Django TDD: How to Test Cached View is Being Served

Tags: django, unit-testing, caching

I wanted to write a Django unittest today to make sure that a cached view is being served from the cache and not being calculated, but I'm running into a wall trying to figure that out.

Is it possible to write a unittest that answers whether a view is pulling from the cache and not recalculating some values and serving the results?

One thing I tried (and this works) is to explicitly delete the cache item and then request the view and confirm that the cache key exists after the view is requested:

```
## from testing module
from django.test import TestCase
from selenium import webdriver
from django.core.cache import cache

class SomeUnitTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.browser.implicitly_wait(5)

    def test_playlist_cache(self):
          cache_key = some_key_generator()
          self.browser.get('http://localhost:8000/video/watch/url')
          self.assertTrue(cache.get(cache_key))
          cache.delete(cache_key)
          self.assertFalse(cache.get(cache_key))

          # The following request should take awhile to process AND
          # It should add the element back into the cache
          self.browser.get('http://localhost:8000/video/watch/url')
          self.assertTrue(cache.get(cache_key), "Video URL is NOT in the cache!")

    def tearDown(self):
         self.browser.quit()
```

This is testing that the cache item is actually being generated after we request the view, and this could be good enough?

The reason I wanted to go further and actually test if the resulting content is coming from the cache is that I am using the low-level caching API to control a variety of aspects of caching the proper element for the right amount of time. It is possible that I made a mistake and that it's overwriting the cached item or not actually pulling from the cache, so I was hoping my unittest could prove that the view is doing what I think it is doing. (I guess I could compare the amount of time it takes to generate the response, but that seems really fuzzy and painful and not the right way to do things.)

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Well you may want to inspect the cache and see that it has what you want in it.

Comment: The way the code works right now is that I generate a unique cache-key corresponding to a particular url (for various reasons). In unit testing, I then 1) delete it from the cache if it's there, 2) assert it's not there, 3) visit the url associated with the key, and 4) check that the key is now in the cache. This (above) covers most of what I want, but it's possible that my cache-creating/cache-saving code is flawed and that I might screw it up in the future. This is why I wanted some magical unittest that says "This view came from the cache." I could write the key out to the template...